# Fastest And Effective Way To Iterate Large DataSet in Java Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, iteration, apache-spark-dataset

I am converting spark dataset into list of hash maps by using below approach, 
My end goal is to build either list of json objects or list of hashmaps
I am running this code on 3.2 millions of rows

```
List<HashMap> finalJsonMap = new ArrayList<HashMap>();
    srcData.foreachPartition(new ForeachPartitionFunction<Row>() {
        public void call(Iterator<Row> t) throws Exception {
            while (t.hasNext()){
                Row eachRow = t.next();
                HashMap rowMap = new HashMap();
                for(int j = 0; j < grpdColNames.size(); j++) {
                    rowMap.put(grpdColNames.get(j), eachRow.getString(j));  
                }
                finalJsonMap.add(rowMap);
            }
        }
    });
```

The iteration is working fine but I am unable to add rowMap into finalJsonMap.

What is the best approach to do this?

Comment: Have you test this code in cluster mode two? I'm afraid that it doesn't work when your driver and executor are distinct.

Comment: As user10947263 stated below, I think your design does not leverage the distribution capabilities of Spark. Think that your code is executed on a lot of different machines which have different memory. If your ultimate goal is to save a JSON file, build your JSON file using Spark transformation and save the JSON file at the end... just my 2 cents

Answer (score 3):

That's really not how Spark works.

The code which, is put in `foreachPartition` is executed in a different context than original

```
List<HashMap> finalJsonMap = new ArrayList<HashMap>();
```

All you can do in such setup is to modify local copy.

This has been discussed multiple times on Stack Overflow and is described in detail in the [official documentation in the Understanding Closures](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#understanding-closures-) section.

Considering the required result (i.e. local collection) there is really nothing else you can do than converting your code to use `mapPartitions` and `collect`. That's however hardly efficient or idiomatic in Spark.

I'd strongly recommend rethinking your current design.